# How can I allow an EC2 instance to send outbound udp?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 which is running a udp server that receives data, and then sends the data back to the client via their ip and some known port that the client is listening on.

I have added outbound udp to ALL, and the specific port I want to send on but for some reason my data is not being received.

Does anyone know how I can see if the EC2 is blocking this somehow?

---

- Image: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
- ufw disabled
- iptables

  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

[image: Outbound rules]

The EC2 instance runs an application which can successfully receive udp data and then it attempts to send it back to the sender but isn't able to. The sender's application is listening for udp data on the same port but for some reason never receives the data. This leads me to believe that something is not configured correctly on the instance for outbound data.

Comment: You should provide infos on OS image type, the current settings for iptables/firewalld/ufw etc, and how your networking is configured in AWS.

Comment: Question is ambiguous. You have "added outbound udp to ALL" - is that iptables, is it security groups, is it NACLs? Have you checked SG / NACLs?

Comment: @TomH Okay I have provided some more information. I'm not sure how to get the iptables because it doesn't seem to display anything (this may be my issue?)

Comment: @Tim to the security group attached to the instance, I have added an image to the op. Would I need to do this for iptables also as I haven't added anything to them.

Comment: Change security group inbound rules. Security groups are stateful. If you don't know what that means ready the AWS documentation, it's excellent.

Comment: @Tim I have changed the inbound rules as well to allow SSH and UDP, inbound works fine as I can send UDP data to the EC2, however when I try to echo it back to the sender, I'm not sure if it even leaves the EC2.

Comment: Use [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) to work out if packets are leaving your EC2 instance. When you next update your question please include incoming and outgoing security group rules.